# Moving cursor from txt box to another

Tags: jquery, text, cursor, move, box

I tried to use this to move from txt box to another but it haven't worked :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="jquery.js"

  ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">

  </style>




  <script type="text/javascript">


    window.onload=function(){

$("input").keydown(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 37) {
     $(this).prevAll("input:first").focus();
     } 
     if(e.which == 39) {
     $(this).nextAll("input:first").focus();
     } 
});

    }

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-315px;top:0px;width:630px;height:662px;border-style:outset;overflow:hidden">    
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px">    
<img src="files/background-001.jpg" width=630 height=662></div> 
<div style="position:absolute;left:73.33px;top:63.87px" class="cls_002">    <input type="text" name="email" size="5.5"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:407.64px;top:62.46px" class="cls_002">   <input type="text" name="email" size="5.5"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:408.42px;top:89.96px" class="cls_002">   <input type="text" name="email" size="5.5"></div>




</body>
</html>
```

Am totaly new to Jquery, i've searched for this but nothing have helped .
Does anyone how to do this with the   .
Does anyone have an idea about this ?

THANX IN ADVANCE

Comment: add relevant html .. I can't find the inputs in the html you provided

Comment: Sorry , i copied the wrong code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above is your HTML structure .. so you need to use `.closest("div").prev('div').find('input')` and `next()` for next div

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 37) {
    $(this).closest("div").prev('div').find('input').focus();
    } 
    if(e.which == 39) {
    $(this).closest("div").next('div').find('input').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;left:73.33px;top:63.87px" class="cls_002">    <input type="text" name="email" size="5.5"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:407.64px;top:62.46px" class="cls_002">   <input type="text" name="email" size="5.5"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:408.42px;top:89.96px" class="cls_002">   <input type="text" name="email" size="5.5"></div>
```